# SiriKit SendPaymentIntent

Tags: ios, sirikit

We are trying to implement SiriKit SendPaymentIntent in our app. We need a local stored data from our main app.

We try to get this string from keychain and user defaults, nothing worked. My question is if we want to get a located stored string, how can we access it with SiriKit.

Comment: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use suiteName for sharing UserDefaults and keychain-access-groups for sharing your keychain. You'll have to add that to your entitlements in the project file.

Here's how I'm using the suiteName for userDefaults sharing:

```
_userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:[config suiteName]];
```